# Using glob to recursively get terminal subdirectories

Tags: python, glob

I have a series of subdirectories with files in them:

```
/cars/ford/escape/sedan/
/cars/ford/escape/coupe/
/cars/ford/edge/sedan/
/cars/ferrari/testarossa/
/cars/kia/soul/coupe/
```

etcetera.

I'd like to get all of these *terminal* subdirectory paths from the root, `/cars/`, using glob (within Python), but not include any of the files within them, nor any parents of a subdirectory. Each one contains only files, no further subdirectories.

I tried using `glob("**/")`, but that also returns `/cars/ford/`, `/cars/ford/escape/`, `/cars/ford/edge`, `/cars/ferrari/`, etc. I do not want these.

I also tried using `rglob("*/")` but that also returns all files inside the terminal subdirectories.

I can get what I need by just globbing the files and making a set out of their parents, but I feel like there must be an elegant solution to this from the glob side of things. Unfortunately I can't seem to find the proper search terms to discover it. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't something standard globbing inherently supports. You'll either need to postprocess, or use a different tool.

Comment: BTW, a note about "using <tool>" restrictions: As https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask indicates, Stack Overflow is focused on **practical**, answerable questions; academic or just-for-the-sake-of-it exercises are frowned on. If you have a _practical_ reason you can't use things other than glob, by all means go into the reasoning behind that restriction and we can try to figure out how to work around it in practice; but generally bending ourselves into hoops to work around a completely artificial restriction is something there's grounding in our rules to push back on.

Comment: There's no restriction to glob per se, I just didn't know the other tool, and wanted to accomplish the filtering in a more elegant manner than gathering all the file names and doing logic to filter out the desired paths afterwards. I thought there must be a way to do it in my glob pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glob` is the wrong tool for this job: traditional POSIX-y glob expressions don't support any kind of negative assertion (extglobs do, but it's still a restrictive kind of support -- making assertions about an individual name, not what does or doesn't exist on the same filesystem -- that doesn't apply to your use case, and Python doesn't support them anyhow). `os.walk()` and its newer children are better suited.

Assuming you're on a new enough Python to support [`pathlib.Path.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.walk):

```
import pathlib

def terminal_dirs(parent):
    for root, dirs, files in pathlib.Path(parent).walk():
        if not dirs:
            yield root
```

---

For older versions of Python, `os.walk()` can be used similarly:

```
import os

def terminal_dirs(parent):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(parent):
        if not dirnames:
            yield dirpath
```

---

Both of these can of course be collapsed to one-liners if in a rush:

```
result = [ r for (r,d,f) in os.walk('/cars') if not d ]
```